# appending ul inside a loop recursively inserts

Tags: jquery

The following code works fine

```
$('.source').each(function(i){ // .source is ul's class
  $('#target ul').append('<li><a>link</a><div>div</div></li>');
});
```

Result:

```
#target ul
 <li>
  <a>link</a>
  <div>div</div>
 </li>
```

But appending ul inside each loop recursively inserts:

```
$('.source').each(function(i){
  $('#target ul').append('<li><a>link</a><ul><li>list</li></ul></li>');
});
```

Result:

```
#target ul
 <li>
  <a>link</a>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
    <li>
      <a>link</a>
      <ul>....</ul>
    </li>
 </li>
```

But it should result like this:

```
#target ul
 <li>
  <a>link</a>
  <ul>
    <li>list</li>
 </li>
```

What is the problem with the code?

```js
$('.source').each(function(){
  
$('#target ul').append('<li><a>link</a><ul><li>list</li></ul></li>');
});
```

```css
.source {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul class="source">
<li>list</li>
</ul>
<ul class="source">
<li>list</li>
</ul>
<ul class="source">
<li>list</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$('#target > ul')` to grab direct children.

The selector `#target ul` gets everything that is a descendant of `#target`, and is a `ul`. However, these elements could be nested a few generations down. By adding `>`, we tell it to only grab the first generation.

```js
$('.source').each(function(){
  
$('#target > ul').append('<li><a>link</a><ul><li>list</li></ul></li>');
});
```

```css
.source {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
<ul>
<li>foo</li>
</ul>
</div>
<ul class="source">
<li>list</li>
</ul>
<ul class="source">
<li>list</li>
</ul>
<ul class="source">
<li>list</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: `$("#target ul")` matches **all** `ul` elements within `#target`. Since you're adding a `ul` element, the second time you do it (for the second `.source`), it matches the `ul` that you just added (when doing the first `.source`). Adding `>` makes the selector only look for a `ul` if it's a **direct** child of `#target`. More: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/

Comment: @BhojendraNepal I also ran into this problem when I started programming. Funnily that's how I found StackOverflow, there was a question similar to this